# How to fetch address from CocoaAsyncUDPSocket

Tags: ios, objective-c, udp, cocoaasyncsocket

Does anyone know how the delegate method for receiving UDP data in CocoaAsyncSockets work when it comes to fetching the source address? Specifically the method

```
-(void)udpSocket:(GCDAsyncUdpSocket *)sock didReceiveData:(NSData *)data fromAddress:(NSData *)address withFilterContext:(id)filterContext
```

The address comes back as `NSData*` but interpreting it using `NSUTF8StringEncoding` returns `null` and `NSASCIIStringEncoding` returns a bunch of garbled characters. How is it supposed to be interpreted?

Comment: Yeah, I want to accomplish is more or less the same. I did however find a more effective solution than the one posted there.

Comment: For IPv4 addresses that is fine. I posted the "more complicated" code there because it works also with IPv6, which is used more and more.

Comment: Aha, gotcha. :) Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Figured out how to do it, the data is in the form of a `struct sockaddr_in*`. After importing `<arpa/inet.h>`you can do the following:

```
struct sockaddr_in *addr = (struct sockaddr_in *)[address bytes];
NSString *IP = [NSString stringWithCString:inet_ntoa(addr->sin_addr) encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
```